# how to avoid call data source function for each new line

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to add a variable lines of the following grid view , 
For example if i choose 5 , compiler called   GetAllProducts 5 times .
how to avoid that and call GetAllProducts once time
Actually each RadComboBox have more than 50000 , so also i need away to avoid memory exception .
so , how to avoid call data source function for each new line

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPOAdd" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="gvPOAdd_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SKU [ Product Name ]">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSKU" runat="server" TypeName="DotShoppingCart.Commercial.Core.Product" SelectMethod="GetAllProducts " />
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbSKU" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SKU") %>' CausesValidation="false" EmptyMessage="Type an SKU" DataSourceID="odsSKU" MarkFirstMatch="true" AutoCompleteSeparator=";" Width="550px" data OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbSKU_SelectedIndexChanged"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvSKU" ControlToValidate="rcbSKU" ErrorMessage="SKU Required" ValidationGroup="ProductRequired" />
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


private void SetInitialRow()
{
  int numberOfRows =1;
  if(NumberOflinesTextbox.Text!="" && int.Parse(NumberOflinesTextbox.Text.ToString())>0)
      numberOfRows=int.Parse(NumberOflinesTextbox.Text.ToString());
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  DataRow dr = null;

  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SKU", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitCost", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TotalCost", typeof(string)));


    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = i;
        dr["SKU"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
        dr["UnitCost"] = string.Empty;
        dr["TotalCost"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    Session["CurrentPoTable"] = dt;

    gvPOAdd.DataSource = dt; //I think here Compiler get into GetAllProducts for 5 times 
    gvPOAdd.DataBind();

}
```

i am thinking about session ?! any idea or code help me ..

Comment: You need to show the code behind for us to help

Comment: I think it should be expected that your data source will be queried by each combo box instance, a databound asp:DropDownLlist will do the same. Consider returning some initial dummy data or even empty data and then use load-on-demand for each combo box. You may even avoid setting a data source for the combo initially, just define load-on-demand setup so it fetches data only once the user expands it.